# Creating href dynamically using array

Tags: arrays, href

I have an array and am populating it in a table using javascript. One of the columns is a hyperlink with one column as its key.

```
for(var i=1;i<arr.length;i++) {
    cell=document.createElement('td');
    if (i == 1) {
        a = document.createElement('a');
        a.setAttribute('href',"javascript:dspl('tblbody',arr[0]);");
        a.innerHTML = arr[i];
        cell.appendChild(a);
    }
    else
        cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(arr[i]));
    row.appendChild(cell);
}
```

However on clicking on any of the hyperlink, only the last value of arr[0] is passed. Is this code wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to create a 2-dimensional table, one with rows and columns.  So there should be 2 nested iterators, i (for rows) and j (for columns).  Where is j?  It looks like you're trying to do both rows and columns with only i, which will not work.

Comment: Well this just a section of the code which is working fine. The only trouble was with href setattribute clause which was not setting properly. The solution is to use this.arr[0]